# How can I fix a black screen issue on resume from suspend?

Tags: 14.04, suspend, intel-graphics

I am looking for a solution to a particular issue with an occasional black screen on resume from suspend on my Thinkpad X230. Some details about the problem:

- The black screen occurs occasionally without any recognisable pattern
- The machine remains responsive. I can type in my login screen password blindly and the machine successfully restores my session, including my screen to switch back on
- I tried different Intel driver and kernel versions without any changes

Has someone ever noticed a similar issue, particularly with respect to the second point (that the machine remains responsive)?

Details about my system:

- Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
- 4.1.1-040101-generic
- Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Have you tried enabling your screen with lightdm? if not please follow the link:  http://linuslinux.blogspot.com/2015/05/troubleshoot-your-dead-screen-with.html  I hope this will help